# How to target all elements, except last one with css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
.outer a:not(:last-of-type) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <a href="#">First</a>
  <a href="#">Second</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Third</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Fourth</a>
  <a href="#">Fifth</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way, to target all `<a>`'s inside div.outer (I can't think of way to target the one inside ) container? The only workaround I can think of is css: `.outer a:not(.last)` and adding .last to last `<a>`. Any ideas? Background: The main idea why I'm doing this, is that I have elements, which line near edge of container, so each of them has to have margin of 10 from right, except last one. In this case, i don't have to type class margin-right-10 in each `<a>`, its just my own style I'm following.

Comment: So you want Third to be matched also?

Comment: Yes, I want it to find all <a>'s except last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you number of levels inside `.outer` is known (or limited) you can extend selector like this:

```css
.outer > * > a,
.outer > a:not(:last-of-type) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <a href="#">First</a>
  <a href="#">Second</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Third</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Fourth</a>
  <a href="#">Fifth</a>
</div>
```

The part `.outer > * > a` makes sure that deeper links are also included into matched set.

**UPD.** Version #2 that also takes into consideration situation when the nested links are the last:

```css
.outer > *:not(:last-child) > a,
.outer > a:not(:last-child) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <a href="#">First</a>
  <a href="#">Second</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Third</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Fourth</a>
  <a href="#">Fifth</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Six</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest so far. It would fail, if last one was <div><a href></a><div>. In my situation it isn't big deal, but for reusable code, it would be a problem.

Comment: Check improved version that should fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
.outer > a:not(:last-of-type), .outer > div a
```

Works as well, but without changing your markup.